# LibVLC Android: Installation guide?

Tags: android, libvlc

I want to learn the VLC library for Android and I found the official porting on github [official porting on github](https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android) however the installation process seems more complicated than I expected.

I'm used to android libraries where you just add the dependency, but here it seems to only on Linux?

Does anybody have a better installation guide? And why do I even need to do this, why can't it just run like any other library? Can I do all of this in Windows?

If you used this library before, I'd appreciate help.

Thanks!

Comment: for xamarin based Android apps, there is this https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp